# How ArrayAdapter really works with ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm confused how the actually ArrayAdapter works? As I was testing with ArrayAdapter and read about it that I have to call the `notifyDataSetChanged();` on adapter or update the listView's adapter (as `listView.setAdapter()`) to update the record in ListView.

Now check this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ExampleArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ExampleArrayAdapter(this,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Here I'm adding record after the listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // it is working fine.
        list.add("Good"); 
        list.add("Bad");

    }

    public void addData(View view){
        // but when I call this method from Button then it doesn't working.
        list.add("New Data Added");
    }
}
```

I don't think so there is any difference between these lines.

```
list.add("Good");
list.add("Bad");
```

and

```
list.add("New Data Added");
```

Both are adding record after the `setAdapter()`;

Then why `list.add("New Data Added");` is not working.

Comment: No answer, just an advice...Use Recyclerview.

Comment: @ElDuderino Thanks but I'm not solving the problem, want to learn.

Answer (score 1):

After `onCreate()` by activity lifecycle run `onStart()` and `onResume()`. `draw` is after `onCreate()`. Therefore 2 items are visible.

`addData(View view)` runs after view is `visible`. To refresh values you need at this place `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`